# Special relativity, what is an transformation with just spatial rotation?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, rotation, matrix-elements

Can someone help me understand how to mathematically represent a transformation of a matrix with a rotation of the spatial axes and why this transformation does not change the unit 3x3 matrix?

This regards the Exercise 11 (a) from A First Course in General Relativity, by Bernard Schutz. Which, for clarification, states:

> Show that the matrix $\delta_{ij}$ is unchanged when transformed by a rotation of the spatial axes.

Thank you

Comment: Do you know what a rotation in ordinary (3D) space is?

Comment: I found examples of it when searching for answers to my questions. If i understand it correctly, spatial rotations in regular 3D space are matricies that rotate the x-,y- & z-axes about the orgin. An example would be... (Accidentaly posted, forgive me for messy writing, this is my first post) 

R_x(alpha) = [1 0 0; 0 cos(alpha) sin(alpha); 0 -sin(alpha) cos(alpha)]

Comment: Note that a rotation matrix is defined by the properties $O^TO=1$ and ${\rm det}O=1$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Properties). I suggest rewriting the first property as $O^T1O=1$, expressing it in index notation, and seeing what you get.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/479421) to type equations and mathematical symbols.